# jQuery click control another click

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I want to pass the click action from `a#click1` to `a#click2`. If I click `a#click1`, then the link `http://www.google.com` should be opened. How to do that?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('a#click1').click(function() {
            $('a#click2').click();
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="wrap1">
    <div id="content1">
        <a id="click1" href="">click</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrap2">
    <div id="content2">
        <a id="click2" href="http://www.google.com">click</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your example is working, whats exactly your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why what you have done wouldn't work but if all you want to do is navigate to the 2nd anchors `href`, you could do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#click1').click(function() {
        window.location = $('a#click2').attr("href");
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is only possible if you declare a click function for the second link like you did for the first.
So this should actually work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('a#click2').click(function() {
                alert('clicked!');
            });  
            $('a#click1').click(function() {
                $('a#click2').click();
            });     
        });
```

It should also work for s right out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
$('a#click1').click(function () {
            $('a#click1').attr('href', $('a#click2').attr("href"));
        });
```